# Multiplos clicks

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
var Tannerie = {

    init : function(){

        $('#prev').mouseover(Tannerie.prevClick);

        $('#next').mouseover(Tannerie.nextClick);

    },

    prevClick : function(){
        $(this).click();        
    },

    nextClick : function(){
        $(this).click();
    }   

}

$(Tannerie.init);
```

Ou seja, quando eu passo o mouse por determinada div ela simula um click. Mas eu queria fazer com que, ao deixar o mouse sobre a div, que fique dando clicks continuos. Tentei usar setInterval mas não funcionou, mas acho que não fiz direito.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o evento/função `.hover()` em conjunto com o `setInterval`:

```
// Cria uma variável para armazenar a referência ao intervalo:
var intervalo;

$('seletor').hover(function () {
  // Caso o mouse entre no elemento começar a clicar:
  intervalo = setInterval(function () {
    $('seletor').click();
  }, 150); // o número é o tempo em milisegundos entre cada clique
}, function () {
  // Caso o mouse saia do elemento parar de clicar:
  clearInterval(intervalo);
});
```

Substitua `seletor` com o que estiver usando. Recomendo colocar o elemento em uma variável (em cache) para que as funções sejam executadas com melhor performance.

Deixei de forma mais genérica caso queira organizar o código como quiser, como colocando o elemento, intervalo e tempo entre cliques como propriedades do objeto `Tannerie`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($('#elem').is(":hover")){
    $('#elem').trigger('click');
}
```

Não testei isso, mas deve funcionar =)

Tirei [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981463/detect-if-hovering-over-element-with-jquery), pra qualquer dúvida.

Comment: O ideal seria colocar um `setInterval` e colocar um `if($('#elem').is(":hover"))` e no `else` desabilitar o `setInterval`.

Comment: Isso vai travar o browser, precisa de um setInterval como disse o Felipe.

Comment: Sim sim, perdão, esqueci de comentar isso. De qualquer modo, quem puder testar, façam um jsfiddle e dêem um feedback pra ver se soluciona o problema do rapaz =)